# How can I convert day of week, Month, Date to Year - Month - Date

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have dates from 2018 until 2021 in a pandas column and they look like this:

| Date |
| --- |
| Sun, Dec 30 |
| Mon, Dec 31 |

Any idea how I can convert this to:

| Date |
| --- |
| Dec 30 2018 |
| Dec 31 2018 |

In the sense that is it possible that knowing the day of the week i.e. (monday, tuesday etc) is it possible to get the year of that specific date?

Comment: what does `df.dtype` give you?

Comment: df.dtype gives ne an Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833121/infer-year-from-day-of-week-and-date-with-python-datetime) conversation. As mentioned, you will probably need to define a range of years, since it is possible that December 30th (for example) falls on a Sunday in more than one year. Otherwise, it is possible to collect a list of years where the input (Sun, Dec 30) is valid. You will probably need to use [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) to convert your strings to a Python readable format.

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate the years from 2018 to 2022 to get every target date's weekday name, then find the match year.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: 'Sun, Dec 30',
                            1: 'Mon, Dec 31'}})
for col in range(2018, 2022):
    df[col] = '%s' % col + df['Date'].str.split(',').str[-1]
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], format='%Y %b %d').dt.strftime('%a, %b %d')

dfn = df.set_index('Date').stack().reset_index()
cond = dfn['Date'] == dfn[0]
obj = dfn[cond].set_index('Date')['level_1'].rename('year')
```

result:

```
print(obj)

    Date
    Sun, Dec 30    2018
    Mon, Dec 31    2018
    Name: year, dtype: int64

print(df.join(obj, on='Date'))

              Date         2018         2019         2020         2021  year
    0  Sun, Dec 30  Sun, Dec 30  Mon, Dec 30  Wed, Dec 30  Thu, Dec 30  2018
    1  Mon, Dec 31  Mon, Dec 31  Tue, Dec 31  Thu, Dec 31  Fri, Dec 31  2018


df_result = obj.reset_index()
df_result['Date_new'] = df_result['Date'].str.split(',').str[-1] + ' ' + df_result['year'].astype(str)
print(df_result)

              Date  year      Date_new
    0  Sun, Dec 30  2018   Dec 30 2018
    1  Mon, Dec 31  2018   Dec 31 2018
```